# Variety measure is always 0 with zonal statistics in QGIS 3.16

Tags: qgis, zonal-statistics

I am trying to calculate two zonal statistics: count and variety.
My raster is a produce of r.raster.area with 4399 groups of pixels within a matrix of no-data values (which are coded as 65535).

My vector layer holds seven hand created polygons, which I have checked for validity, both with the built-in Validity Check algorithm and visually.
As I need Variety, the only tool I can use is the QGIS Zonal statistics tool in the Processing Toolbox. When I run the analysis, I get correct values for Count, but Variety is always 0 (which is impossible, as all the polygons hold many different values).

Could this be a problem with the high number of unique values (4399)?

Comment: I suspect this is a bug. When you need `Variety` measure, will you also select either `Minority` or `Majority`, or both of them along with `Variety`?

Comment: Together with minority and majority I get a value for variety !=0, without 0.

Answer (score 1):

You need to also either Minority or Majority when asking for Variety, as pointed out by @Kazuhito and @Jochen Schwarze. It works smoothly when done so.